# How to force ghc's profiler to step deeper into the libraries?

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

I'm trying to profile my program. So I compile it with `-prof` and `-auto-all` flags and run with `-P` to get detailed profiling report:

```
$ ghc --make -prof -auto-all Test.hs
$ ./Test +RTS -P
```

Here  is a piece of profiling report:

```
COST CENTRE              MODULE  no.    entries  %time %alloc

  main                   Main   266           1   0.0    0.0
   run                   Main   273       21845  99.3   99.7
    sz                   Main   274       21844   0.0    0.0
   size                  Main   268       21845   0.7    0.3
```

It seems that `run` consumes all time and memory. It calls a lot of functions from various libraries, and I'm quite sure that most time is spent in one of them, but I can't figure in which one.
How can I get more detailed report? I hope that putting lots of `SCC` annotations manually is not the only way.

**Update**. For now I "solved" the problem by copying sources of libraries to my program directory. This allows GHC to treat them as part of program, not as external libraries.

Comment: Maybe [visual-prof][1] can help somehow? [1]:https://hackage.haskell.org/package/visual-prof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a gprof-type profiler - [pretty weak, for these reasons.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343)

You can use [GHCi](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Debugging#Dynamic_breakpoints_in_GHCi) to find performance issues the same way you would find infinite loops, [by this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) in this manner:

> 6.3 Infinite loops  On glasgow-haskell-users on 21 Nov 2007,
>   pepe made the following suggestion for
>   detecting the cause infinite loops in
>   GHCi. Assuming the offending function
>   is named `loop`, and takes one
>   argument:
>
> 1.enable the flag -fbreak-on-error (`:set -fbreak-on-error` in GHCi)
>
> 2.run your expression with :trace (`:trace loop 'a'`)
>
> 3.hit Ctrl-C while your program is stuck in the loop to have the debugger break in the loop
>
> 4.use :history and :back to find out where the loop is located and why.

The only difference between any performance problem and an infinite loop is - infinite loops waste 100% of the time, while performance problems waste a lesser percent.
So you might have to break into it a few times.

Comment: thanks for the links. It seems that usefulness of this technique is a consequence of lack of good profiling tools (especially for ghc).

Answer (score 4):

For the profiler to discriminate library functions, there have to be cost-center annotations on them.  You can do this two ways:

1. Recompile the libraries of interest with `-p -auto` so that library functions get annotated with SCCs.
2. Insert SCC annotations around probable time-consuming library calls in your code.

Comment: All the libraries are installed with `cabal install --enable-library-profiling`. Isn't it the same as `-p -auto`?

Comment: No, it's the same as -p. I.e. the libraries get compiled to support the profiling calling convention, but with no cost-center annotations. I think that cabal install --enable-executable-profiling will actually pass the flags you need (despite the name), but I'm not certain off the top of my head.